# How to sort in vim starting from some column/character

Tags: vim

How to sort following text starting from column 5:

```
123456789
000 123
013 122 
122 013
123 000
```

I want to get this:

```
123 000 
122 013
013 122 
000 123
123456789
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following vim command helped me:

```
:sort /\%5v/
```

### Explanation

besides some plain options (like u,i,!,n) sort can receive
regular expression /{pattern}/. In this case there are two options:

#### A. Sort by skipping matched

default - with no [r] flag specified -
in this case for each line the text matched with {pattern} is skipped, so
**sort is done on what comes after the match**.

Examples from documentation:

**A1. Example - sort starting from virtual column 5**
our case - *sort on the text at virtual column 5 (thus ignoring the difference between tabs and spaces):*

> ```
> :sort /.*\%5v/
> ```

**A2. Example - sort on the second comma-separated field**

The logic is: skip text until first comma is found:

> ```
> :sort /[^,]*,/
> ```

#### B. Sort only matched - [r] flag specified

i.e. *sorting is done on the
matching {pattern} instead of skipping past it as described above
... to sort on only the first three letters of each line*:

```
:sort /\a\a\a/ r
```

### Reference

Please check [:help :sort](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:sort) for more details/options

Comment: ...where the command itself is `:sort`. Checking the help entry for that command, you can see it takes a regex as a parameter that is used to *ignore* the part of the line matching that regex when it sorts, starting the sort after the match.

Comment: @Ben Thanks, I have updated the answer with explanation, examples and references.

Answer (score 1):

...The following also works, which basically sorts the 5th column

`:sort /.*\%5v/`